# NoClassDefFoundError while using scopt OptionParser with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, noclassdeffounderror, scopt

I am using Apache Spark version 1.2.1 and Scala version 2.10.4. I am trying to get the example [MovieLensALS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/MovieLensALS.scala) working. However, I am running into errors with [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) library which is a requirement in the code. Any help would be appreciated. 
My build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "Movie Recommender System"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.2.0"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
```

and the errors I am getting are the following:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scopt/OptionParser
    at MovieLensALS.main(MovieLensALS.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scopt.OptionParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 8 more
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

On running sbt assembly to build the jar, I receive the following errors:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]         ^
```

Edit: As per Justin Piphony's suggestion the solution that was listed in sbt's [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#using-published-plugin) page helped fix this error. Basically creating a file assembly.sbt in the project/ directory and adding the line 
`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")`

Note that the version should be added according to the version in use.

Comment: How did you build your jar?

Comment: @JustinPihony  Using sbt package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to package `scopt` in your jar. sbt doesn't do this by default. To create this fat jar, you need to use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

Comment: Edited the question with details of sbt assembly

Comment: Did you follow the setup for your version of sbt. It sounds like the plugin wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: Could you provide some details? I downloaded the sbt tool and installed it in my box.

Comment: The details are on the github page for sbt-assembly. There are 3 possibilities depending on version. So you'll need to check which version you have

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven to package your spark project, you need to add `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin which helps to package dependencies:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>make-assembly</id>
    <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
    <phase>package</phase>
    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```