# Spark Examples NoClassDefFoundError scopt/OptionParser

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scope, noclassdeffounderror

I've build Spark 2.1 source code successfully.
However, when I run some of the examples (e.g., `org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.BinaryClassification`), I get the following error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scopt/OptionParser`

I tried to run those examples using Spark 2.1 pre-built version (`examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar`), and I got the same error. Spark 1.6 pre-built version works (`lib/spark-examples-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar`). There are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324314/noclassdeffounderror-while-using-scopt-optionparser-with-spark) related to this error, but they don't seem to be applicable because Spark `examples` folder does not have any `.sbt`file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. To avoid the error, `scopt_x.xx-x.x.x.jar` should also be submitted using `--jars`. When you build Spark examples, in addition to `spark-examples_x.xx-x.x.x.jar`, `scopt_x.xx-x.x.x.jar` will be built too (in my case in the same target folder `examples/target/scala-2.11/jars`).

Once you have the jar file, you can submit it with your applications:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
   --jars examples/target/scala-2.11/jars/scopt_x.xx-x.x.x.jar \
   --class org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.BinaryClassification \
   --master ...
```

Comment: Man this is crazy. I've been doing spark - and even contributed to mllib - for 4 years but could not figure this out. The `bin/run-example` **really** should have taken care of this